# mongoose model query method syntax

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I use mongoose model to access MongoDB database such as

```
MyModel.findByID(...)
MyModel.save(...)
MyModel.aggregate(...)
```

Are the methods name and query syntax the same as if I am doing with MongoDB shell?

```
db.mycollection.findByID(...)
db.mycollection.save(...)
db.mycollection.aggregate(...)
```

In other words, does mongoose model inherits every collection method from MongoDB as listed here in https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/#collection ? And does mongoose have built-in wrapper function around the MongoDB collection methods with different syntax?

Just wondering if I call MyModel.method() I can use the same syntax as I would use with MongDB shell.

Comment: The actual "methods" are not "exactly" the same as they are in fact wraped in logic that most notably includes ensuring the database connection is actually made. That said the actual "syntax" regarding "queries" or "aggregation pipeline" operations is **exactly** the same. Mongoose just "passes through" such information, with "maybe" some alterations i.e Casting types, include version key or discriminator etc. That seems to be what you are really asking. Yes?

Comment: Also FYI there is a "collection" accessor available on all models that actually does point to the underlying `Collection` object from the native driver. i.e `MyModel.collection`. So you can in fact use this directly. But care should be taken if you do, since various things that mongoose is "looking after for you" ( i.e the database connection being present, and of course "casting" ) are not functions of the native driver methods.

Comment: Yes. you basically answered my question. Is there a list of such wrapper methods by mongoose?

Comment: [mongoosejs.com - model.js](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model-js)? Note also that some methods like `.findOneAndUpdate()` have a different "options" syntax to the core driver. This is mostly because the mongoose method of that name existed "before" the core driver method, which was just the core method of `.findAndModify()` for all previous releases, and still the underlying call of the mongoose method. I think.

Comment: core driver method refers to monggodb node.js driver method?